# mysql query to return the record that has the MAX value of a column

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am currently having the database which represented by this db schema.

database schema

[image]

Here i want a query to get the accommodation name which is in a given destination with highest rating value that is having a room id with price per head value which is smaller than a given value.

Sample data of the rating table

Ex: I want to get the hotel name which has a room with price per head value below than 50$ that is situated in New York with highest rating value.
[Sample rating table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsakx.jpg)

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't tested it but following query should work:

```
select ac.name as hotel
from accomodation ac
inner join room r
on r.accomodation_id = ac.accomodation_id
inner join rating ra
on ra.rating_id = ac.rating_id
where 
ac.destination_id in (select destination_id from destination where name = 'New York')
and 
r.room_id in (select room_id from room where price_per_head < 50)
order by ra.value desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: @Strawberry why?

Comment: @Harshil See answer nearby

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked with other records. I want the max value of the rating.value not the rating_id

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for pointing it out. I was clearly out of my mind.

Comment: @dineshalwis can you please provide some sample data in your question?

Comment: @dineshalwis Please try the edited answer. It should work now.

Comment: Always glad to help!

Comment: @Strawberry You may want to look at the edited answer.